# Rails: How to read the value of a select without a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running into a perplexing issue that I can only resolve partway, and hopefully, someone more experienced can tell me whether I can achieve what I wish, or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I have a Rails 4 application which uses Devise and CanCan. I'd like to make a small subset of application functionality available to guest users (not logged in). I can achieve this by specifying a get route to a controller method and using `link_to` to reach that method. I cannot, however, figure out how to get the value of a select box to pass along as parameters on that page without making that view a form using `form_tag` (there is no model associated with this view).

I can pass hardcoded params along like so:

```
<%= link_to "Month", activities_search_month_path(:resource_id => 4) %>
```

but I'd rather have something like:

```
<%= link_to "Month", activities_search_month_path(:foo => :resource_id) %>
```

where the second symbol refers to the value of a `select_tag`. This second example delivers a literal value of "resource_id" when I dump the `:foo` key unless I convert my view to a form.

If I turn the view into a form by enclosing all the `erb` in a form_tag, I get a `401 Forbidden` error, after which the Devise sign in form is rendered. My guess is that any time you want to process a form, Rails (or Devise) demands authentication on some level. The behavior is the same when I use `button_to` rather than `link_to`, since `button_to` wraps itself in a form under the covers.

How can I set that resource_id argument in my `link_to`, or will I be forced to create a guest user access level and silently log in guest users? It's important for the UX that users can access this functionality with the least amount of effort possible.

Thanks in advance.

Addendum: quick_search method from controller

```
def quick_search
puts "quick search 0"
    if(params[:time_period] == 'today')

      @resource = Resource.find(params[:resource_id])
      @site = Site.find(params[:site_id])

      @time_period_string = "Activities for #{localize_date(Date.today)} at #{@resource.name}, #{@site.name}"
puts "quick search 1"
      if user_signed_in?
puts "quick search 2a"
        @activities = Activity.where("system_id = ? and start_date = ? and activity_status_id = ? and resource_id = ?", current_system_id, @today, 2, params[:resource_id])
      else
puts "quick search 2b"
        if(Setting["#{current_subdomain_not_signed_in}.quick_search_guest_access"] == 'true')
puts "quick search 3a"
          current_system_id = current_system_id_not_signed_in
          @activities = Activity.where("system_id = ? and start_date = ? and activity_status_id = ? and resource_id = ?", current_system_id, @today, 2, params[:resource_id])
        else
puts "quick search 3b"
          redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
        end
      end
end
```

Note: the quick_search method is never entered. CanCan (or maybe Devise) steps in immediately and redirects to sign in:

Console output:

```
Started GET "/activities/quick_search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-12 18:01:58 -0700
Processing by ActivitiesController#quick_search as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "systems"."subdomain" FROM "systems"
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-12 18:01:58 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "systems"."subdomain" FROM "systems"
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 282.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Ability.rb

```
can :quick_search, Activity
can :search_day, Activity
can :search_week, Activity
can :search_month, Activity
```

The odd thing is that `link_to` quick_search fails with a 401, but `link_to` the other three methods works fine -- I just can't get parameters to them dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CanCan(Can?) you can define a special ability for guests.

How does your `Ability`-model look? 
Which controller are handling the action that you want to view?
How do you authenticate with CanCan in this controller? 
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/CanCan-2.0
Under the "Defining Abilities" you can see a non-user example.

Fixing CanCan is probably the best option, if you do not want to:
For the part with the link and select box it would be easiest to handle as a form and then handle the redirect in the controller, it could also be done with a remote ajax form.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

This should work:

```
<% form_tag Activity, activity_quick_search_path, remote: true do %>
  <%= select_tag :resource_id...%>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<%end%>
```

Edit after comments:

The culprit here is(was) an:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Causing Devise to redirect to sign in page.

However, if you have CanCan you shouldn't need the `authenticate_user`.

Short example:
With only Devise I would do:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_news, except: [ :index, :new ]

  def index  
    @news = News.all  
  end

  def show    
  end

  def new
    @news = News.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @news = News.new(news_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'News created' if @news.save!
    redirect_to @news
  end

  def update
    @news.update! news_params
    redirect_to @news
  end

  def destroy
    @news.destroy!
    redirect_to News
  end

  private

  def news_params
    params.require(:news).permit(some_attributes)
  end

  def set_news
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

How it looks with CanCanCan:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index  
  end

  def show    
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    flash[:notice] = 'News created' if @news.save!
    redirect_to @news
  end

  def update
    @news.update! news_params
    redirect_to @news
  end

  def destroy
    @news.destroy!
    redirect_to News
  end

  private
  def news_params
    params.require(:news).permit(some_attributes)
  end
end
```

Which I find super neat  
Hope that this can help as well.

Comment: I'm using the CanCan continuation, so yes, CanCanCan, and there is a can :quick_search, Activity line for users without a role (in the else block where I'm branching by role). I *believe* that CanCan is set up correctly, but Ajax is an interesting alternative. I'm not following your thinking on the redirect, however. Would I not simply run into the same 401 due to the fact that I'm sending params from a form?

Comment: I think I need to see your controller which you are handling this in. If you only get error when you add a form, I think you need different authorization for current action.          Can you add the controller in question and your Ability model?

Comment: Updated. All the controller methods mentioned are set up the same way, same branching, with the exception of all the puts statements.

Comment: Do you have any before_actions in your controller?

Comment: We were thinking the same thing, and I failed to add an exception for quick_search in before_action authorize_user. Now the method can be run, but I still need a way to pass the resource_id selected by the user to the controller.

Comment: You should look at CanCanCan load_and_authorize_resource. You want a guest user to be able to do a quick_search where they can select resource from a select_tag?

Comment: This was the offending line: before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :search_day, :search_week, :search_month, :quick_search] where I simply forgot to add :quick_search, and yes, the original point was to pass along a user selected resource_id in a link_to

Comment: CanCan has really sweet methods for all that 

Comment: The problem boiled down to skipping authentication on the quick_search method, which led me down a rabbit hole. I actually understand CanCan  but simply missed adding a symbol on a single line of code. Please edit your answer to show that the solution was to fix the before_action :authenticate_user!, except: line by adding a symbol for :quick_search so that you can get some points. What I thought was going on with forms was not going on for the reasons I had assumed, so this question/answer pair is next to useless, but you need some rep.